# Postgres Datebase multi foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a table described as following:

```
                                     Table "public.lead"
           Column            |              Type              |                Modifiers                
-----------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------
 id                          | character varying(36)          | not null
 reference_code              | character varying(20)          | not null
 country_id                  | character varying(36)          | not null
 language_id                 | character varying(36)          | not null
 locale_id                   | character varying(36)          | not null
 from_country_id             | character varying(36)          | not null
 to_country_id               | character varying(36)          | not null
 customer_id                 | character varying(36)          | not null
 user_id                     | character varying(36)          | 
 from_date                   | date                           | not null
 from_date_type              | smallint                       | not null default (0)::smallint
 from_street                 | character varying(200)         | 
 from_postalcode             | character varying(25)          | 
 from_city                   | character varying(100)         | 
 from_country                | character varying(50)          | 
 from_apartment_type         | character varying(255)         | not null default '0'::character varying
 from_floor                  | smallint                       | 
 from_rooms                  | numeric(3,1)                   | 
 from_people                 | integer                        | 
 from_squaremeter            | integer                        | 
 from_elevator               | smallint                       | not null
```

I am trying to create foreign keys for (country_id, from_country_id, to_country_id)
As you can see all these 3 fields has a relation with  table.
But when i try to create these foreign keys, i got the following error.

> ERROR: insert or update on table "lead" violates foreign key constraint "lead_to_country_id" Detail: Key (to_country_id)=(United Kingdom) is not present in table "country".
>   Details

Comment: The error is caused by an `insert` or `update` statement. Please [edit] your question and all those statements.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often related to a missing key.

When you try to create a foreign key AFTER an insert statement, SQL searches for those keys in the table which has the Primary Key (PK).

Eg.

table_with_PK

```
col1(Pk) | col2| coln ...
id_1       foo    bar ...
id_2       nan    ana ...
```

table_connected_to_table_with_PK

```
col1(Fk) | col2 | etc...
id_1
id_2
id_3 (Error because not present in table_with_PK)
```

So first create the table which has your primary keys, then populate it.

Second create the table with foreign keys, make foreign keys(Fk), then populate/update it, in order to have coherence in your database.

Check postgresql documentation on constraints: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it: You are trying to set the `to_country_id` column value to `'United Kingdom'` which does not exist in the referenced `country` table. Insert that value into the `country` table and retry.